# How to concatenate strings in a loop?

Tags: string, matlab, loops

I'd like to create an inputdlg with various lines with similar names like Test 1, Test 2, Test 3 and so. So I'm looking for some way to concatenate strings in a `for` loop. I tried something like:

```
 formatSpec = '''Test %d'',';
    a = sprintf(formatSpec,1);
    for i = 2:numtest
        a = strcat(a,sprintf(formatSpec,i));
    end
```

but it's not working for inputdlg. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
for i = 1:10
    line_name = sprintf('Test %d', i);
    prompt{i} = line_name;
end
input_result = inputdlg(prompt);
```

[image]