# looping to concatenate string

Tags: r, string, loops, concatenation

Sorry for asking a basic question. I've tried looking for the answer in the  following links but with no luck

[How to concatenate strings in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115832/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-a-loop)

[How to concatenate strings in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115832/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-a-loop)

[C concatenate string with int in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169562/c-concatenate-string-with-int-in-loop)

So, here is a reproducible example. I've a list called house i.e

`house <- c("Dining Room", "Drawing Room", "Number of Bathrooms", "5", "Number of Bedroom", "5", "Number of Kitchens", "1")`

where every element in the house list is character. Now I want to create another list where if the element of list is of character length of one(representing a number) then it should concatenate with the previous string element. This is output I am expecting.

`"Dining Room", "Drawing Room", "Number of Bathrooms 5", "Number of Bedroom 5", "Number of Kitchens 1"`

I have tried running a loop but the output is not similar to what I expect.

`for(i in house){
  if(!is.na(nchar(house[i])) == 1) {
     cat(i,i-1)
  } else{
    print(i)
  }
}`

Comment: I have to say, this is a very odd for your data to be in in the first place. I’d try very hard to avoid getting such data, if at all possible: Since there must be some process generating this data, I suggest changing that process to generate the data in a different, logically consistent format.

Comment: A number could be `22` for instance (2 characters length), no? Eitherway, you could fully vectorize this by doing `indx <- which(nchar(house) == 1) ; house[indx - 1] <- paste(house[indx - 1], house[indx]) ; house[-indx]`, for instance

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. Below is one. If anything is unclear, let me know.

```
house <- c("Dining Room", "Drawing Room", "Number of Bathrooms", "5", 
           "Number of Bedroom", "5", "Number of Kitchens", "1")

# helper function that determines if x is a numeric character
isNumChar = function(x) !is.na(suppressWarnings(as.integer(x)))
isNumChar('3') # yes!
isNumChar('Hello World') # no

foo = function(x) {
  # copy input
  out = x
  # get indices that are numeric characters
  idx = which(isNumChar(x)) 
  # paste those values to the value before them
  changed = paste(x[idx - 1], x[idx])
  # input changes over original values
  out[idx - 1] = changed
  # remove numbers
  out = out[-idx] 
  # return output
  return(out)
}

foo(house)
[1] "Dining Room"           "Drawing Room"          "Number of Bathrooms 5"
[4] "Number of Bedroom 5"   "Number of Kitchens 1"
```

Comment: You don't nee a loop. You could simply do `idx <- which(isNumChar(house))` and this solution looks all too familiar